# Scala validation

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm new to Scala and Gatling. I'm just trying to understand the documentation.

I've written a basic scenario and I would like to confirm that the page I'm going to contains a certain string.

```
 import scala.concurrent.duration._

    import io.gatling.core.Predef._ // 2
    import io.gatling.http.Predef._
    import io.gatling.core.session.Session._



    class RecordedSimulation extends Simulation {

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL("baseurl")
        //.inferHtmlResources()
          .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
            .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
              .acceptLanguageHeader("en-GB,en;q=0.5")
                .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0")

    val headers_0 = Map("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1")


    val scn = scenario("RecordedSimulation")
        .exec(
            http("request_0")
              .get("/Homepage.asp")
                .headers(headers_0)
            .check(bodyString("Welcome")).exists
              )


    //setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
    setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(15) during (8 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol))
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

I keep getting a type mismatch error on the line that contains the `.check(bodyString("Welcome")).exists`

Thanks

Comment: It seems your closing bracket is in the wrong place: Try `.check(bodyString.substring("Welcome"))`. And see the [docs](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check/#http-response-body) anyway ;)

Comment: I'll give it a go, thank you.  I've been reading to docs but as I'm not too good with Scala, I'm not sure how it all pieces together.

Comment: I am getting an error returned when trying to compile the script:  value is not member of io.gatling.core.check.DefaultFindCheckBuilder